# Google People API - Not returning email addresses

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-people-api

I have working the auth flow to authenticate users using google oauth2. Including the default permissions I added the `contacts` to get access to the users contact.

Once the user accept the authentication then I can get the contacts using this endpoint:

`/v1/people/me/connections?personFields=emailAddresses&access_token=****`

As you can see I added the `emailAddresses` but the response for this api call only return the email address for 1 contact of 149

response example:

```
{"connections"=>
  [
    {"resourceName"=>"people/c471****", "etag"=>"%EgIBC..."},
    {"resourceName"=>"people/c471****", "etag"=>"%EgIBC..."},
    ........
    {
      "resourceName"=>"people/c471****", "etag"=>"%EgIBC...",
      "emailAddresses"=>[
       {"metadata"=>{"primary"=>true, "source"=>{"type"=>"CONTACT", "id"=>"5123*******"}},
        "value"=>"*****@gmail.com", "type"=>"home", "formattedType"=>"Home"}
      ]
    }
    .........
    {"resourceName"=>"people/c471****", "etag"=>"%EgIBC..."},
    {"resourceName"=>"people/c471****", "etag"=>"%EgIBC..."},
  ],
  "totalPeople"=> 149,
  "totalItems"=>149
}
```

Why if the response return 149 contact only one of them contains the email address? I could access to the email for all the contacts?

Comment: Are you sure there are actually emails on the other contacts? Could you verify the e-mails exist at https://contacts.google.com/?

Comment: That's right there aren't emails on the other contacts... these contacts are generated when I add a contact in the phone so normally just contain the name and mobile number. There is another way to obtain the contacts email? I sent emails to a lot of people with that account but these are not saved in contacts.google.com

Comment: If you want contacts that you sent e-mails to, then check the ["Other contacts"](https://contacts.google.com/other) (contacts that are not in any group) section of Google Contacts. As for the Google People API, it only returns contacts that are placed in groups.

Comment: is there any way to fetch this "other contact" list from people API ?
@AmosYuen

Comment: Other contacts read access was added. See https://developers.google.com/people/v1/other-contacts